# Deleting files only with specified permissions in Linux using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I want to delete only files with 777 permissions in Linux (Ubuntu) using Python Script but it deletes all the files I create.

Output right now: Script is sending notification about file creation and is deleting all the files while script is running.

Expected output: Script sends a notification when the user creates a file with 777 permissions and then deletes it. Not touching other files for example only read permission files.

```
import os
from time import sleep
import subprocess

# folder = os.getcwd()
# folder = r'C:\Users\TheAlestGuy\Desktop\TestPu\Testing'
folder = "/home/alen/Desktop/TestFolder/Teting"

try:
    while True:
        files = os.listdir(folder)

        for file in files:
            if os.stat(folder).st_mode & 0o777:
                os.remove(f'{folder}/{file}')
                subprocess.Popen(['notify-send', "User is trying to create file with 777 permissios"])
                sleep(5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Script terminated, no more files will be deleted :)")
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `os.stat(file).st_mode` returns more info than just access level.

```
$ touch testme
$ ls -lah testme
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ex4 ex4 0 Mar  2 00:10 testme

$ python3
>>> os.stat("testme").st_mode == 0o664
False
>>> oct(os.stat("testme").st_mode)
'0o100664'
```

And as N. Kerm said, you bitwise operator isn't right choise in here

There is masks for different parts for `st_mode` You can use them like this:

```
>> from stat import S_IRWXU, S_IRWXG, S_IRWXO
>> u = os.stat("testme").st_mode & S_IRWXU # User permission
>> g = os.stat("testme").st_mode & S_IRWXG # Group permission
>> o = os.stat("testme").st_mode & S_IRWXO # Others permission
>>> oct(u)
'0o600'
>>> oct(g)
'0o60'
>>> oct(o)
'0o4'
>>> oct(u+g+o)
'0o664'
```

further reading: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html

Comment: Good point, I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

On your line here:

```
if os.stat(folder).st_mode & 0o777:
```

You're using the bitwise-and operator. The result with be nonzero if any permissions are set for any user. You probably want to use `==` instead.

Also, I am not sure if this is intended, but `os.stat(folder).st_mode` is only checking the permission of the folder. I imagine you want something more like this:

```py
path = os.path.join(folder, file)
if os.stat(path).st_mode == 0o777:
    os.remove(path)
```

Edit: As ex4 pointed out, the `st_mode` may contain other info as well. So it may be best to slice only the last 3 digits:

```py
path = os.path.join(folder, file)
if oct(os.stat(path).st_mode)[-3:] == '777':
    os.remove(path)
```

Comment: There is a little more elegant way to read permissions tha just slicing it. There is bitmasks available for different permissions.